# When using a sizer in wxPython, and you add a widget, what it means if you set -1 as proportion?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I'm learning `wxPython` from a tutorial. In the example script for `listbox` section, I encountered this line:

```
hbox.Add(self.listbox, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
```

The second parameter of Add method is proportion, and I know that the value of `wx.ID_ANY` is -1. What does it mean here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the tutorial you are using is incorrectly adding wx.ID_ANY in there. I am not sure what wxWidgets does under the hood if you pass a negative proportion, but the standard way to add a widget/sizer to another boxsizer is to specify a non-negative proportion (0, 1, 2, etc...) depending on whether the child of the sizer can change its size in the main orientation of the sizer - where 0 stands for not changeable and a value of more than zero is interpreted relative to the value of other children of the same sizer.